# How to lock-down Access 2007 design?

Tags: permissions, microsoft-access

I have an Access 2007 database (.accdb) and I want to lock down settings being changed to it, specifically under `menu->Access Options->Current Database->"Display Form"` etc.

I understand you can save it as a .accde which locks down a number of options, but this does not seem to accomplish what I want.

How can I lock down "Access Options->Current Database"?

I'd need to lock down the database per the file, not per user.

Comment: Have you considered removing that option from the menu completely for that particular database? I know it's possible in Access 97, and Microsoft has a tendency to keep features.

Comment: That would be great. How can that be done?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unfamiliar with Access past 97. Check GoogleBing for "hiding menu options" or similar.

Comment: @RandolphWest Is this suppose to be a client setting, or a file setting? I found something like `DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo` but that's all it said, no idea where to put that.

Comment: It's a file setting. The idea is that you can modify the UI on a per-database level.

Comment: Create an ACCDE file.  This will lock down the ribbon and all design features so they cannot be modified.  Don't lose the original ACCDB file though or you will get locked out as well.